# How to cool large amount of liquids in a home kitchen?

Tags: food-safety

I like to prep and freeze large amounts of soup at once but have come to understand that I probably have a food safety issue cooling them in my refrigerator.

I had been putting them is a cube shaped cambro, but have noticed that it takes way, way too long to get it down to 40°F.

My research turned up a lot of food safety strategies for commercial kitchens with a lot of equipment/space that I don't have.

What methods can a home cook use to get a large amount (say, ten quarts) of liquid down to safe temperatures in time?

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/62988/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16540/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/88135/67 ;

Comment: Please see the answers to the questions @Joe has linked above.  All of those suggestions are directly applicable to your question.  As such, I'm flagging your question as a duplicate.